# Regex matching everything before 4 digits

Tags: regex, match

What's the regex for matching everything before 4 digits in a row appear somwhere, but also include the 4 digits in the match?

Comment: Please supply sample data, desired output and some attempts you've made. Last I checked, SO wasn't a "ask a question with no effort to get given free code" service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this regex should be good enough :

```
(^.*?\d{4})
```

Explanation:

`^` assert position at start of the string

`.*?` matches any character

`\d{4}` match a digit [0-9] four times

Check out the working here:https://regex101.com/r/gO0aT9/1

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. It's very much appreciated by a total regex noob.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive lookahead with 2 capture groups.

For example:

```
^(?=((.+)[0-9]{4}))$
```

https://regex101.com/r/dR4oQ7/1

---

*<sup>Considering an answer was posted, I thought I'd post my own answer even though I [added a comment requesting sample data and an effort by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723455/regex-matching-everything-before-4-digits/28723714#comment45733612_28723455).</sup>*

Comment: What's the advantages of a lookahead in this case?

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE None that come to mind. Just another way to get what OP wanted. [@MohitBhasi answer is a nice alternative too.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28723694/3000179)